# In xamarin forms possible to set fontsize as small,large,medium for label

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my project, I had Title ,Subtitle and content I need to use 18Px for content, 20Px for Subtitle, 22Px for title.

Comment: To get a useful answer, please show XAML containing elements that you want to be those font sizes. Then someone can guide you as to what you need to add/change in that XAML.

Comment: Could you provide more code for this case? If you want to set the fontsize of Label, you could use the NamedSize enumeration like Small, Middle, Large with FontSize property or set with double value like 18,20, 22 directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for size and attribute:

```
<Label FontSize="Medium" />
```

check this link for size option: [Fonts in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#understand-named-font-sizes)